# If user dosen't have Google Drive authority, Google Apps Script couldn't get active user email with "Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()"

Tags: google-apps-script

I met a question in process of development,  if the user did not be authorized to access "Drive",  the system can not return current user email address via "Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()" when user access a Google site,  the system return empty value.
  But a month ago it is OK, I could get user email address via "Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()" in my Google applications, now couldn't. Why?

Sample Coding for a Google Site:

```
function doGet(e) {
    var app = UiApp.createApplication();
    var La = app.createLabel();
    app.add(La.setText(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()));
    return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on who has access to your app - is it you alone, anyone or anyone, including anonymous. 
If it is set to anyone or anyone, including anonymous, have you logged in to your gmail account when you visit the google site.